# How to approximate "import package.*" in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I'm writing a Python program that can parse a binary protocol consisting of messages. Each message has an identifier, followed by type-specific data. I've structured my app so that each message-type is represented by a (sub)class, located in its own module inside my package:

```
messages/
   __init__.py
   MessageTypeOne.py
   MessageTypeTwo.py
   ...
```

From my main file (which is inside the same package, but I don't think it matters) I would like to do the equivalent of

```
import package.*
```

That is, I would like all module types to be loaded, but *not* imported in to the local namespace (i.e. not what `from package import *` would do). I prefer not to list the message types explicitly (simply adding a file should be enough), but using something similar to the `__all__` construct from `from bla import *` would be acceptable.

I've found a way to accomplish this by looping over `os.listdir(__path__)`, and `importlib.import_module()`'ing each found file, but this feels overly hacky... Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Update:
Depending on the usage (e.g. decoding for logging or sending a single message), I don't always want to import every message type, so statically importing them in `__init__.py` is not desirable

Comment: I suggest to place all message types in a single module and then import that module (why would you use multiple modules each containing exactly one class?). Otherwise just import them in `__init__.py` (`from .MessageTypeX import ...`) and then you can, again, `import messages` and the message types will be scoped via `messages.SomeMessageType`.

Comment: Just put all the classes in the same module.

Comment: Putting them all in a single module would technically work, but I prefer to have 20 files of 100 lines each, than a single 2000-line file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably have `__init__.py` do the importing:

```
# in __init__.py
from . import MessageTypeOne
from . import MessageTypeTwo
...
```

If you don't want to do that, you can use `__import__`:

```
__import__('package', fromlist=['*'])
```

This performs the same initialization as `from package import *` would, but without actually binding any names in the local namespace. Note that it won't initialize any submodules that `from package import *` wouldn't, so you still need to configure the `__all__` list in `__init__.py`.

Comment: but I could populate `__all__` dynamically from within the package? Or must `__all__` be a static list?

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the syntax for relative imports. Here for future reference: `__import__('subpackage', globals=globals(), level=1, fromlist=['*'])`